# Schedule stop and start of a service in Weblogic WLST

Tags: weblogic, scheduled-tasks

I using Weblogic 10.3.6 in my Enterprise environment.
i have a cluster of 10 servers serving 15 web service.
every month i want to stop a specific service at 00:00 and start that at 05:30
how can i schedule that job for weblogic

Comment: Can you clarify when you say "to stop a specific service" ? Do you need to stop the traffic to the service or do you need to stop the web service application (for maintenance for instance) ?

Comment: mean of service is web service application or enterprise application deployed in weblogic. i want to stop an application deployed in weblogic and i want stop that application for running a database job and i don't want to process any traffic by that application.

Comment: You can achieve this with a WLST script that will stop (stopApplication) and start (startApplication) your application. Schedule your script with a cron job.